# Execute postinstall program with administrator privileges in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, elevated-privileges

I'm trying to run another installer at the end of the installation (`postinstall`). The installer needs administrator provileges. So `PrivilegesRequired=admin` was added and the error still was there.

Error message below:
[image]

> Unable to execute file:
> C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Multi Webcam Video Recorder\webcam.exe
>
> CreateProcess failed; code 740.
> The requested operation requires elevation.

```
#define MyAppName "Multi Webcam Video Recorder"
#define MyAppExeName "webcam.exe"

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Files]
Source: ..\src\webcam.exe; DestDir: {localappdata}\{#MyAppName}; \
    Flags: ignoreversion

[Run]
Filename: {localappdata}\{#MyAppName}\{#MyAppExeName}; \
    Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{#MyAppName}}; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [`postinstall` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=postinstall), the program is by default executed with original privileges, even if the installer itself is running with Administrator privileges. To keep the (Administrator) privileges of the installer, add [`runascurrentuser` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=runascurrentuser):

```
[Run]
Filename: {localappdata}\{#MyAppName}\{#MyAppExeName}; \
    Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{#MyAppName}}; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser
```

---

If the main installer does not have the Administrator privileges, see:
[Execute postinstall program (sub installer) with administrator privileges in Inno Setup even if the main installer does not have them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74125021/850848)